# Using statically for blogger images

Tags: javascript, blogger

Currently, blogger images are loaded from `1.bp.blogspot.com` or `2.bp.blogspot.com` or `3.bp.blogspot.com`

Is there a way, to load the uploaded images from statically.

Example: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zz2hQ1thv8w/V_YilPYNecI/AAAAAAAABFQ/OwC5dN0Rbo4eoXTrQ82E4k3arwfzxeBqwCK4B/s1600-e365/Figure-1-New-Ballard-score-Reprinted-with-permission-from-Ballard-JL-Khoury-JC-Wedig.png

CONVERTED AUTOMATICALLY TO

https://**cdn.statically.io/img/**2.bp.blogspot.com/-zz2hQ1thv8w/V_YilPYNecI/AAAAAAAABFQ/OwC5dN0Rbo4eoXTrQ82E4k3arwfzxeBqwCK4B/s1600-e365/Figure-1-New-Ballard-score-Reprinted-with-permission-from-Ballard-JL-Khoury-JC-Wedig.png

I mean: any script to automatically add `cdn.statically.io/img/` before the image url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple javascript code to replace the start of all images, don't forget to wrap it within a `<script>` tag:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
    img.src = img.src.replace(/(http|https):\/\//,'https://cdn.statically.io/img/');
});
```